# My PHP Form will not refresh properly

Tags: php, web

So when I hit submit on the form that is displayed, the page (if working properly) should refresh, and the ELSE statement should be displayed instead, but I have 2 problems

The else statement is not displayed until I manually refresh the page
The Pub Score is not updated until the page is manually refreshed either, I think my code placement might be what's causing it, but I tried to put my form as far down as I could, I'm out of ideas, any help would be great thanks.

```
<?php
require_once('header.php');
require_once('connectdb.php');
require_once('sessioncheck.php');
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATA);

$user_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_GET['username']));

$query = "SELECT * FROM blah WHERE username = '$user_name'";

$data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($data); 

if (mysqli_num_rows($data) != 0) {


if ($row['havemic'] == 1) {
    $micstatus = "Yes";
} else {
    $micstatus = "No";
}
?>




<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title><?php echo $user_name . ' profile' ?></title>
</head>

<body>

<?php 
$commenduser = $user_name;
$query = "SELECT * FROM blah where commenduser = '$commenduser'";
$data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
$lowerusername = strtolower($username);
$loweruser_name = strtolower($user_name);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 0) {
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {


        $commendplayer = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['commendplayer']));
        $commend = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['commend']));
        $comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['comment']));

        if (empty($comment)) {
            echo '<p class="error">Please fillout a comment before submitting</p>';
        } else {

        $query = "INSERT INTO commend (commendby, commenduser, comment) VALUES ('$username', '$user_name', '$comment')";
        mysqli_query($dbc, $query);


        if ($commend == true) {
            $query = "UPDATE blah SET points=points+1 WHERE username='$user_name'";
            mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
            echo '<p class="success">Your commendation has been submitted with + 1 account points.</p>';
        } else {
            echo '<p class="success">Your commendation has been submitted with no affect on the users account points.</p>';
        }


    }
}
}  else {
    echo '<p class="success">You have already submitted a commendation for this player.</p>';
}
?>


<div id="accsettings">
<table cellpadding="5">

<tr><td><label for="username" class="reglabel">Username: </label></td>
<td><label for="username" class="reglabel"><?php echo $row['username']; ?></label></td></tr>
<tr><td><label class="reglabel">Pub Score: </label></td><td><label class="reglabel">

/*This value 'points' should be updated to the new value after form submit */
/*As well the ELSE statement near the bottom should be displayed*/
<?php echo $row['points'] ?></label></td></tr>
<tr><td><label for="steamname" class="reglabel">Steam Name: </label></td>
<td><label for="steamname" id="acclink"><?php echo '<a href="http://steamcommunity.com/id/' . $row['steamname'] . '">' . $row['steamname'] . '</a>'; ?></label>
<tr><td><label for="favchar" class="reglabel">Prefered Hero: </label></td>
<td><label for="favchar" class="reglabel"><?php echo $row['favchar']; ?></label></td></tr>
<tr><td><label for="language" class="reglabel">Spoken Language: </label></td>
<td><label for="language" class="reglabel"><?php echo $row['language']; ?></label></td></tr>
<tr><td><label for="playernote" class="reglabel">Player Note: </label></td>
<td><label for="playernote" class="reglabel"><?php echo $row['note']; ?></label></td></tr>
<tr><td><label for="micstatus" class="reglabel">Has a Mic and VO-IP?</label></td>
<td><label for="micstatus" class="reglabel"><?php echo $micstatus; ?></label></td></tr>

<tr><td colspan="2">Players Comments</td></tr>


<?php
if ($row['commendby'] != $username && $lowerusername != $loweruser_name) {
?>
<tr><td><br></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><p class="success">Player Commendations/Comments</p></td></tr>
<tr><td><br></td></tr>


<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?username=' . $user_name; ?>">
<tr><td><label for="comment">Leave a comment</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="comment" class="regtext" /></td></td>
<tr><td colspan="2"><label for="commend" class="right">Commend Player?</label><input type="checkbox"  class="right" name="commend" value="yes" /></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><input id ="submit" type="submit" class="button1" name="submit" value="Submit" /></td></tr>
</form>

<?php
} else {
/*This is what should be being displayed after the form is submitted. But it is not.*/
    $query = "SELECT * FROM blah where commenduser = '$commenduser'";
    $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
        echo '<tr><td><br></td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td><br></td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td><label  class="reglabel" for="commendedbyy">Comment From: ' . $row['commendby'] . '</label></td>';
        echo '<td><label class="reglabel">' . $row['comment'];
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="submit" />';
        echo '</form>';


    }

}
?>  

</table>

<?php
} else {
    echo '<p class="error">' . $user_name . ' is not a registered account.</p>';
}
}
else {
    echo '<p class="error">You must <a href="login.php">Log In</a> to view this profile.</p>';
}
?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
require_once('footer.php');
?>
```

Comment: i dont think you can have a parameter if you are using the post method. you need to do <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" />

Comment: Everything gets submitted / called to and from the database just fine, it's just the form doesn't load properly. @AMayer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$row` is first grabbed from the database and then the database is updated.

You can do one of three things, the last being the simplest:

1. You can refactor the code to change the order
2. Reload the data using another query after the update
3. Once you update the points then update the array (i.e. do `$row['points'] = $row['points'] + 1;`)

Comment: Any idea how come the ELSE statement for the form won't show after submission and only when I manually refresh the page?

Comment: This is caused by the same issue. The value for `$row['commendby']` has been taken from the database before the update occurs.